# Extract distinct graph-linked values from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, graph

| ColumnA | CoumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |

In this,

- 1 is link with 5
- 5 is link with 2
- 2 is link with 1
- 1 is link with 4
- 4 is link with 8
- 1 is link with 5
- 5 is link with 2

So the output what I want is distinct values that are linked with each other

| output |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 8 |

Comment: So what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I used union but it will return rows based on the number of union queries I put. If I use union five times then it will return five link records. Whereas I dont know in tables there would be more rows linking.

Comment: Your sample data and output seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that attempts to solve this problem is the following:

- extract distinct combinations of your pairs
- count the frequency of first column values
- extract each pairs whose first column appears more than once, or that appears in the second column at least once
- linearize your data

Each of these steps is done in a separate cte.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(ColumnA, ColumnB)    AS col1, 
                    GREATEST(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS col2
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT col1, col2, 
           COUNT(col1) OVER(PARTITION BY col1) AS cnt_col1
    FROM cte t1
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE cnt_col1 > 1 
                          OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte2 t2 WHERE cte2.col1 = t2.col2)
)
SELECT col1 FROM cte3 UNION SELECT col2 FROM cte3
```

---

If you instead need to begin from a specific index and are looking for all linked nodes in the graph, you need a recursive query:

- *Base step*: extracts unique records of <ColumnA, ColumnB> for a specific id
- *Recursive step*: extracts consecutive records on cte.ColumnB = tab.ColumnA.

Then it's just sufficient to gather distinct values of ColumnB in the output. In the following case ColumnA = 1, if you want to change it, you need to change the value in the filtering condition of the base step `WHERE LEAST(ColumnA, ColumnB) = <your_value>`

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(ColumnA, ColumnB)    AS ColumnA,
                    GREATEST(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS ColumnB
    FROM tab 
    WHERE LEAST(ColumnA, ColumnB) = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tab.ColumnA, tab.ColumnB 
    FROM cte 
    INNER JOIN tab
            ON cte.ColumnB = tab.ColumnA
)
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB FROM cte
```

**Output** (for id = 1):

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 8 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/M8r_psQ1).

Comment: How can I apply where conditions ? Suppose I want to see records where ColumnA=1 , then it should display values link with 1 and its respective values. ( it should not include 3 and 10) and in case ColumnA=3 then it should give 10 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following is what you are looking for, but I believe your sample data is not correct in respect of the desired output:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
  ColumnA INT,
  ColumnB INT
)


INSERT INTO #TempTable (ColumnA, ColumnB)
VALUES (1, 5), (2, 1), (3, 10), (4, 8), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5)

SELECT group_id
      ,ColumnA
      ,ColumnB
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 as group_id,*
    FROM #TempTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,ColumnB, ColumnA
    FROM #TempTable
) DS
GROUP BY group_id
        ,ColumnA
        ,ColumnB
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The idea is to unite the data in two groups and get only this records with count 2 - meaning we have x-y and y-x scenario.

The output of the above query is:

[image]

From there with another nested query or CTE you can get only the columns you want.

Comment: This *may allow* for (3,10), (3,10) to include both 3 and 10, whereas it's really one link only.

Answer (score 0):

Bsed on the simple data and the expected output, I think this is what you are looking for :

```
with cte as (
  select  ColumnA, ColumnB
  from mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ColumnA, t.ColumnB
  from mytable t
  inner join cte c on c.ColumnB = t.ColumnA
)
select ColumnA AS linked_values
from cte
group by ColumnA
having count(*) > 1
union 
select ColumnB
from cte
group by ColumnB
having count(*) > 1
```

Result :

```
linked_values
1
2
4
5
8
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/y2Mx4Y81)